# How do I replace slash '/' with whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace '/' with whitespace in a string unless if it's between 'mg' and 'number'
`'ABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE/ZIDOVUDINE MYLAN 300 mg/150 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé'`

Becomes

`'ABACAVIR LAMIVUDINE ZIDOVUDINE MYLAN 300 mg/150 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé'`

and how can i do it with an array of multiple lines

['ABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE TEVA 600 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé' 'ABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE ZENTIVA 600 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regex pattern for your conditions. You can use the following constructs:

- A negative lookbehind asserts that what precedes the slash is not `mg`
- A negative lookahead asserts that what follows is not a digit.

---

```
import re
my_string = 'ABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE/ZIDOVUDINE MYLAN 300 mg/150 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé'
print(re.sub('(?<!\bmg\b)\/(?![0-9])',' ',my_string))
#ABACAVIR LAMIVUDINE ZIDOVUDINE MYLAN 300 mg/150 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest a solution simple and readable also for beginners and that doesn't use any import module.

In my code I simply parse the string character by character with a for loop and check if the current character is "/".

I use enumerate because it allows me to access both the index and the value of the current character during the iteration.

In case "/" is found I use [Python's slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) to check if "mg" is coming before it and use this information to replace it with whitespace or not.

**Solution**

```
data = ['ABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE TEVA 600 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé' 'ABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE ZENTIVA 600 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé']
new_data = [] 

for line in data:
    result = "" 
    for key, value in enumerate(data):
        if value == "/" and data[key-2:key] != "mg":
            result += ' '  # replace with white space
        else:
            result += value
    new_data.append(result)

print(new_data)
```

**Output**

```
['ABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE TEVA 600 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculéABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE ZENTIVA 600 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find all `/` occurrences except `mg/number` and then replace them:

```
import re

string = 'ABACAVIR/LAMIVUDINE/ZIDOVUDINE MYLAN 300 mg/150 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé'
result = re.sub('\/[^mg\/\d+]', ' ', string)
```

Output:

```
ABACAVIR AMIVUDINE IDOVUDINE MYLAN 300 mg/150 mg/300 mg, comprimé pelliculé
```